# PREG_ or Regex Question

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-split

I'd like to match the last instance of `/` (I believe you use `[^/]+$`) and copy the contents of the next four or less numbers until I get to a dash `-`.

I believe the "right" method to return this number is through a preg_split, but I'm
not sure. the only other way I know is to explode on `/`, array reverse, explode on `-`, assign. I'm sure there's a more elegant way though?

For instance

```
example.com/12-something // get 12

example.com/996-something // get 996

example.com/12345-no-deal // return nothing
```

I'm unfortunately not a regex guru like some of you folks though.

Here is an ugly way to do the same thing.

```
$strip = array_reverse(explode('/', $page));

$strip = $strip[0];

$strip = explode('-', $strip);

$strip = $strip[0];

echo (strlen($strip) < 4) ? (int)$strip : null;
```

Comment: The regex you could use would be: `/\/([^-]{0,4})/` The number would be in the first capture group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
    $str = "example.com/123-test";
    preg_match("/\/([\d]{1,4})-[^\/]+$/", $str, $matches);
    echo $matches[1]; // 123
```

It makes sure that the `###-word` part is at the end and that there are only 1-4 digits.

Comment: This will not always match the last slash. For instance: `example.com/123-test/blabla`

Comment: When I wrote the comment there was a different version of regex ;)

Comment: preg_match("/\/([\d]{1,4})-[^\/]+$/", $page, $etc);
print_r(array_pop($etc)); Worked great

Answer (score 1):

A match on `/\/(\d{1,4})-[^\/]+$/` should fit the bill with the number in the first capture var. My apologies, I don't write PHP and I don't want to deal with `preg_match`'s interface, but that's the regex anyhow.

If PHP supports non-slash regex delimiters these days, `m#/(\d{1,4})-[^/]+$#` is the version with fewer leaning-toothpicks.

Comment: Don't you think that the `#` look like 4 thoothpicks put together? ;)

Comment: hobbs I get Array ( [0] => training/2-wedding-training [1] => )
$etc = preg_split("/\/(\d{1,4})-[^\/]+$/", $page);
print_r($etc);
as a result